# Can I use wildcards in the web.config location path attribute?

Tags: authentication, iis-7, web-config

In IIS 7 I try to deny access to all files with the extension .xml for all users.

I tried the following setting in my web.config file:

```
<location path="*.xml">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

But then getting any file results in an internal server error.

It works if I deny access to the individual files but this solution does not buy me much as I do not know all .xml files in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web.config: Wildcards in location and authorization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375208/web-config-wildcards-in-location-and-authorization)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*.xml" verb="*" 
             type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

By the way you could alternatively store all of your xml files within the [App_Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537930/appdata-web-applications-data-directory-how-secure-is-it) directory. Storing files of any type in this directory will not be served to the web.

Comment: Can this same approach be applied here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096577/servicestack-api-documentation-in-swagger-ui-behind-the-closed-doors ?

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use a request filter:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <fileExtensions>
        <add fileExtension=".xml" allowed="false" />
      </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled across this when searching for a way to change the security applied to all actions within a controller in a legacy application (ASP.NET MVC). I thought I need some sort of wildcard, but simply providing the path including the controller segment is enough:

This allows anonymous access to all actions within `FooController`.