# MVC: Restrict access to execute .aspx scripts in specific path location

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7

For some reasons, sometimes may occurr that some .aspx files could appear in /Uploads/Photo/Avatar folder, and I want to restrict access to deny execution .aspx or any other scripts inside this folder.

Anyway, files like .jpg .gif and other should be accessed (but not executed) by IIS.
What is the best way to configure web.config, or maybe setup Routes in global.asax

Please consider, that the standart forms authentication is not used (there is no roles)

project is using:
MVC3
IIS7
ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

you can use the location tag, but that does not support wild card mapping. you will find this answer helpful.

[Can I use wildcards in the web.config location path attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631384/can-i-use-wildcards-in-the-web-config-location-path-attribute/1631525#1631525)